# Why a class included in Infinispan's white list still throws the error 'No marshaller registered'?

Tags: wildfly, marshalling, infinispan, jcache, jsr107

I'm using Infinispan 10 and Wildfly 17. I have an infinispan.xml file with a white list of classes where I specify the marshaller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:10.0">
    <cache-container>
        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller">
            <white-list>
              <class>org.jsr107.ri.annotations.DefaultGeneratedCacheKey</class>              
              <regex>java.sql.*</regex>  
              <regex>java.util.*</regex>
            </white-list>            
        </serialization>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

I followed [this documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/developing/developing.html), chapter 9.1.2 Java Serialization Marshaller

But it doesn't seem to work for a specific class, which is org.jsr107.ri.annotations.DefaultGeneratedCacheKey. The error message is:

```
Cannot marshall 'class org.jsr107.ri.annotations.DefaultGeneratedCacheKey': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No marshaller registered for Java type org.jsr107.ri.annotations.DefaultGeneratedCacheKey
```

How can I add that class to Infinispan's white list?

More info:

I load the CacheManager at startup, like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = CacheSetup.class.getClassLoader()
URI uri = URI.create("infinispan.xml");
final CacheManager jCacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager(uri, classLoader);
```

The Infinispan dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsr107.ri</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-annotations-ri-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-cdi-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

In standalone.xml, this is all that I find related to Infinspan.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:distributable-web:1.0" default-session-management="default" default-single-sign-on-management="default">
    <infinispan-session-management name="default" granularity="SESSION" cache-container="web">
        <primary-owner-affinity/>
    </infinispan-session-management>
    <infinispan-single-sign-on-management name="default" cache-container="web" cache="sso"/>
    <infinispan-routing cache-container="web" cache="routing"/>
</subsystem>

    <caches>
        <cache name="simple"/>
        <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
    </caches>

    <passivation-stores>
        <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
    </passivation-stores>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:8.0">
    <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
        <local-cache name="passivation">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="sso">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="routing"/>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
        <local-cache name="default">
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
        <local-cache name="passivation">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
        <local-cache name="entity">
            <object-memory size="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="local-query">
            <object-memory size="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
    </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: How are you loading the cache container?  Are you using the embedded infinispan?  If so I think the configuration needs to go into your standalone.xml rather than an independent file.  Can you post more details about your configuration?

Comment: I tried with Infinispan/Master and was not able to reproduce it. Could you please share what was the Infinispan version that you are using?

Comment: @teacurran I edited my question and added the code that loads the cache container, an also the parts of the standalone.xml that refer to Infinispan. Is it 'better' to have that configuration in the standalone.xml? Do you have a link about how to do that?

Comment: @Diego I edited my question and added the Infinispan dependencies in my pom.xml

Comment: Building my web app places the file infinispan.xml inside the .war file, and it had to be placed at /WEB-INF/classes

Comment: @teacurran what is the cache ( I mean what is the name of the cache ) that your application is using?

Comment: I posted an answer. Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error in my app was caused by reading the cache via these annotations:

```
@Interceptors(org.jsr107.ri.annotations.cdi.CacheResultInterceptor.class)
@CacheResult(cacheName = "measurementCount")
```

Other caches in my app are read without those annotations, and it works:

```
Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager(...).getCache().containsKey(...)
```

Comment: The caching interceptors are wrapping the key in `DefaultGeneratedCacheKey`, so it makes sense that the exception doesn't happen when accessing the cache directly.